# How to change inner text of HTML tags without removing them

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-re

Assuming I have "semi" HMTL string like

```
some_string = "sometext<body>someText<h1>Text</h1>Worldt<p>And some text here<br>Text.</p></body>HereAlsoText"
```

I need to replace all tags in the string but with keeping all HTML tags (including br):

```
"UPDATED<body>UPDATED<h1>UPDATED</h1>UPDATED<p>UPDATED<br>UPDATED</p></body>UPDATED"
```

The following code works, but cannot do anything with `<br>` tag and text before and after html (outside of `body` tag, in this case):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(mod_string, "html.parser")


# Find all tags
tags = soup.find_all()
# Loop through child tags
for tag in tags:
    # Check if tag is a string
    if tag.string:
        if tag.name != 'br':

            # Replace string
            tag.string.replace_with("TEST")

for parent_tag in tags:
    if not parent_tag.string:
        parent_tag.string = ''.join(
        ["TEST"
            if not re.match(r'<[^>]+>', str(t)) else str(t)
            for t in parent_tag.contents])
```

Appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: `tag.string.replace_with()` to replace a string content but, in general, works for tag as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep it more simple, just select all the text nodes and replace the text as you have already tried in your example:

```
for e in soup.find_all(text=True):
    e.string.replace_with('UPDATE')
```

##### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

some_string = 'sometext<body>someText<h1>Text</h1>Worldt<p>And some text here<br>Text.</p></body>HereAlsoText'

soup = BeautifulSoup(some_string, 'html.parser')

for e in soup.find_all(text=True):
    e.string.replace_with('UPDATE')

print(soup)
```

##### Output

```
UPDATE<body>UPDATE<h1>UPDATE</h1>UPDATE<p>UPDATE<br/>UPDATE</p></body>UPDATE
```